# Check if type is dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How to check if variable is a python dictionary?

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    if type(v)==dict:
        print('This is a dictionary')
```

This code is not working

Edited:

Solved. type(v) is working. I made mistake when used name 'dict' for my dictionary.

Comment: Use `isinstance` --> `if isinstance(v, dict):`

Answer (score 8):

To properly check if `v` is an instance of a `dict` you can use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
for k,v in your_dict.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        print('This is a dictionary')
```

---

Note: Change your variable name `'dict'` to something else, as **you're masking the buit-in name**

Answer (score 4):

To begin with, never name your variables as python keywords, so don't use `dict` as a python variable name, since it is replacing the python built-in keyword `dict`. Instead use something like `my_dict`

You should consider using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if a variable is a dictionary, instead of [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

From the docs of `type`:

> The isinstance() built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.

Also since you are only using values, consider only iterating on them using `my_dict.values()`

```
for v in my_dict.values():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        print('This is a dictionary')
```

Comment: Thank U. Code started working when I renamed my dictionary.

Comment: Great! Glad to help @DeepSpace Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it helped you :) Also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `isinstance(object, classinfo)` than checking if `type(object) == classinfo`

```
for k,v in dict.items():
    print(isinstance(v, dict))
```